# Set device language as locale?

Tags: ios, localization, nsdate, locale, nsdateformatter

In one of my localized apps, Spanish is the default language. However, the user could have set English as default language, and its region to to "Spain".

The problem is that within my app I use this code:

```
int day = (60*60*24);
NSDate *nextNextDay = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:(day*2)];
NSString *someString = [[dateFormatter stringFromDate:nextNextDay] capitalizedString];
NSLog(@"The day: %@", someString);
```

The result is the name of the day in the default locale, which is (in this scenario) spanish. So, instead of that I would get "Monday" as result, I will get "Lunes" instead. This, of course, is very ugly when the rest of the app is in English.

How can I solve this without hard-coding any locales?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not hardcode locales?

You could do this:

```
NSString *userLocale = [[NSLocale currentLocale]localeIdentifier];
NSString *userLanguage = [userLocale substringToIndex:2];
if([userLanguage isEqualToString:@"en"]){

    //English

}
if([userLanguage isEqualToString:@"es"]){

    //Spanish

}
```

Hope this helped

Comment: Eventhough its hardcoding, it is usable.